# working with time series data in which target variable is in percentage

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, arima

I have following dataset,

```
Month     efficiency
Jan        80%
Feb        90%
March      95%
```

I want to use timeseries models to forecast efficiency of upcoming month in terms of percentage. Efficiency can not be greater than 100%.

How can i ensure my future forecast value is in percentage itself while implementing Arima, LSTM or other algorithms.